# Assistance in setting up orthogonal distance regression [scipy.ODR]

Tags: python, scipy

So I'm a bit confused trying to read the documentation for scipy.ODR.

Let's say you have an overdetermined linear system

```
def model(x,y,z,A,B,C):
  m=Ax+By+Cz

#where A,B,C are given coefficients, and x,y,z are calculated from another setup of equations for the variables you are actually trying to solve for (a,b)

def calculate_xyz(A,B,C):
   x=2a+b
   y=2a-b
   z=3a+b
   mod=model(x,y,z,A,B,C)
```

Now this can be solved through traditional minimization via sum of squared residuals

```
def calculate_xyz(A,B,C):
   x=2a+b
   y=2a-b
   z=3a+b
   mod=model(x,y,z,A,B,C)
   return (mod-data)**2

minimize(calculate_xyz,x0=(1,1),args=(A,B,C))
```

However, in this instance, the data has error associated with it. To that end, from what I can tell the way to do this is ODR, however I'm having difficulty understanding how to transfer the above model/setup to an ODR format for scipy.

Additionally, the entire purpose behind me doing this is because I'm trying to solve the errors for the response (a,b). I know for traditional minimization, the Hessian is provided that gives you your variance, but this assumes no errors in explanatory variables. How does one calculate the Hessian/covariance matrix incorporating errors in the explanatory? I don't see any discussion on error outputs in the ODR docs.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!